# Ansible playbook with JSON output

Tags: ansible

I'm new to Ansible and I'm having a problem passing a variable into `json_query` to read elements from a JSON array.

working line:

```yaml
    Interface:{{ result.json | json_query('[2]')}}"
```

I would like to replace number 2 for a variable that will change.

I tried:

```yaml
- name: Interfaces
  debug:
    msg:
    - Interface:{{ result.json | json_query('[ item ]')}}"
  with_sequence: start=2 end=5
```

but it failed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide both: output of debug task `-debug: var=result` and output of failed task

Comment: fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Error in jmespath.search in json_query filter plugin:\nunhashable type: 'list'"}

Comment: Hi user10761553, welcome to SO. You will experience better success if you pay strict attention to the formatting of your question. We cannot guess whether you have left off the opening `"` in your actual playbooks or not. It makes providing you with answers harder than necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you were very close, but what you really want is:

```
- debug:
    msg:
    - Interface: "{{ result.json | json_query('[' + item + ']') }}"
  with_sequence: count=3
```

You were correct that inside the jinja2 mustaches `item` is a variable, but python does not auto-concatenate things, so you must expressly ask for `"["` and `item` to be joined together

Comment: It is working now after your suggestion. Thank you sir!